# Oracle, determine if value is null

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sqlplus

If I run the following query in sqldeveloper (or sqlplus):

```
    select *
    from passwordlog
    where exists(
              select USERUID 
              from otherTable 
              where uid=2
            );
```

and the `where exists` evaluates to false, the result is just empty.

The result isn't either null or a boolean, so I test if the length of this result is greater than 1.

But I just started to wonder. What is the result really? Is it an empty string? Or null? And is there a better way to perform this check, than checking on the length of the returned string?

I want to be able to do something like this (assume we have the Oracleconnection, OracleDataAdapter etc.):

```
string query = select *
               from passwordlog
               where exists(
                   select USERUID 
                   from otherTable 
                   where uid=2
              );
```

And then in a C# method:

```
public void SomeMethod() {
   if(query == null) { } ...
      or maybe
   if(query == false) { } ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: The result is an empty set, i.e. no rows returned.

Comment: If there is no match then you will end up with a result set having 0 rows. Use the most appropriate method to test e.g. `OracleDataReader.HasRows` or `OracleDataReader.read() == true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you check only whether something "exists" or not (at least, that's what your C# code looks like), if you - instead of `select *` - use `select count(*)`, you might fix it as `COUNT` will return 0 (zero) if there's nothing to be returned, so you'd easily check that in your C# code.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, I did not think of that. It's good enough to solve my problem

Comment: No definitely not; I too don't use facebook :)

Comment: Bummer, @Rahul; I thought I was unique :( (Just kidding!)

Answer (score 2):

It's an empty result set or record set. So the below query can be simplified to. Thus no rows would be selected since the predicate is `false`. So your check if no.of rows > 1 would always be false as well

```
select *
from passwordlog
where false
```

To check, if you just do below, the record count would be `0`

```
select count(*) from passwordlog where 1 = 0
```

Comment: `Where false` is invalid  and boolean can't be used in Oracle SQL

Comment: `false` is not allowed in SQL, but one could use `select *
from passwordlog
where 1 = 0`

Comment: @KaushikNayak wasn't talking about Oracle ... that's more an explanation

Comment: Rahul : Never mind. I just wanted to ensure that someone coming here seeking an answer later should not blindly copy paste an answer and say it isn't working :-)

Answer (score 2):

Usually in an `EXISTS` subquery you would refer to the record in the main query, e.g. find out whether there exists an otherTable entry for the passwordlog's userid:

```
select *
from passwordlog p
where exists (select * from otherTable o where o.uid = p.uid);
```

Your subquery, however, is not correlated to the main query. It is either true or false, no matter what passwordlog record you are looking at. This means you either select all passwordlog records or none at all.

As to your question when the expression evaluates to false (no uid=2 record in otherTable): This is the case you select no records. You are asking whether this is an empty string or null, but keep in mind: you have selected no rows. If you had selected some rows, you could have asked for a specific column in a specific row, e.g.: what is the password in the first row or what is the user ID in the second row? But of course you cannot ask "what is the columns in the zeroth row".

As to merely checking whether a uid=2 record in otherTable exists, that would be

```
select exists (select * from otherTable where uid = 2);
```

in standard SQL returning a boolean. In Oracle however you must always select from a table (the dual table for one row) and there is no boolean datatype. Hence:

```
select 
  case when exists (select * from otherTable where uid = 2) then 1 else 0 end
from dual;
```

Another option would be counting the records, but you don't want to read all records and keep counting all the while, when you only want to know whether at least one record matches. In Oracle you can use rownum for that:

```
select count(*)
from otherTable
where uid = 2 and rownum = 1;
```

Oracle will stop at the first match and hence return either 0 or 1, depending on whether a uid=2 record in otherTable exists.

Answer (score 0):

alter the code like this and try..

```
    select count(*)
    from  passwordlog
    where exists (select useruid
                  from othertable 
                  where uid=2)
```